# Aggregation based on the median of probability distribution

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a big data set (75 Million rows) consists of 12 columns. The rows are repeated holding the same values except for the last 2 columns that constitute the probability distribution 
[image]

As we can see in this snipping, regarding the first 10 columns, the rows are equal in values and the last 2 ones (value_count, value) are the probability distribution for the rows. I want to aggregate those rows to be one row based on the median of the probability distribution of value_count, value

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: edited after the comment.

you can get the median easily by using `summary`.

```
df_result = your_table.select("value_count", "value").summary("50%")
```

The result is a dataframe with one row and 2 columns. You can join it to your original dataframe if you want to: `your_table.select("col1", .. , "coln").distinct().join(df_result, "outer")`

Alternatively there are the functions `approx_quantile` and `percentile_approx` which could probably do the job without using a join (like above)

Comment: Thanks @Christopher for your answer, but where the aggregation, I meant in the question do aggregation based on the median of (value_count, value), SO the 27 rows in the snipping will be one and last 2 columns will be one holding the median value of value_count, value

Comment: Thanks again @Christopher, maybe I didn't explain my point clearly, I want to do aggregation (group by) based on the median of (value_count, value) together. In the snipping that I post on the question, there is a sample of 27 rows of data, Those 27 rows should be one row, and the 12 columns will be 11 after the aggregation (the first 10 columns and the last 2 columns will be median (value_count,value))